# three-step visual studio build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

My VS 2010 solution has let's say 1 native C++ dll project and 1 c# wrapper project. What I want is a pure magic. My solution has 32 and 64 bit configurations, mostly because of native dll. I'd like to build the solution so that c# dll includes both 32bit and 64bit native dll as resources in c# dll. Then I will unpack proper bitness in runtime and use it (this is not a problem). My question is how do I configure VS solution to build both bitnesses and then put them into the C# project before it builds?

I could probably do a clever .msbuild script, but then I won't be able to build nicely from VS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Right-click on the C# project in Solution Explorer and select **Unload Project**.
2. The project will be unloaded. Right-click on the project again and select **Edit *.csproj**.
3. Now you can edit the project file inside Visual Studio. *.csproj file has rather simple XML format.
4. Go down the *.csproj file right before `</Project>` closing tag.
5. Add the following lines:

```
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <MSBuild Projects=".\..\NativeLibrary.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=x64"/>
        <MSBuild Projects=".\..\NativeLibrary.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32"/>
    </Target>
```

No, you can right-click on the project file in Solution Explorer and select **Reload Project**.

Also, you will need to add 32-bit and 64-bit *.dll files to resources. I have used this approach for a long time and it works perfectly. You can build your C# project from inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually i'm doing now the build of that native project instead of the whole solution in <beforebuild> as the solution is huge. Then pre-build step to copy natives into Resources subfolder. It works!

Comment: Thanks again, everything nicely integrated with build server, I now have the magic assembly I dreamed about :)

Comment: You are welcome. Actually I am using even more complicated approach as you do. I also compress native 32-bit and 64-bit libraries using LZMA algorithm (from 7-Zip) before including into resources.